# How to use NUnit Addins under PNUnit

Tags: c#, nunit, pnunit

I want to use NUnit Addins and run tests using PNUnit.
It is possible or am I just doing something wrong?
It works individually, but when I run through PNunit it ignores NUnit Addins that use EventListeners.

Thanks in advance for your answers and please forgiveness if that stupid asking the network information is not found.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible at present; PNUnit doesn't set up the enviroment needed to load NUnit Addins.

There's one exception to this, which is that any classes with the [NUnitAddin] attribute and defined in your test assembly will be loaded as addins. So you might be able to get the addins you want loaded that way.